# django celery beat arguments with imported class functions from another library

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I'm trying to get a function to work in my django project with celerybeat that imports a class based function from a wrapper library.  I've been reading that celery doesn't work with classes too easily. my function login_mb doesn't take an argument but when I try register and call this task I get an error `Couldn't apply scheduled task login_mb: login_mb() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`
Is this because of self in the wrapper function imported?

What could I do to get this to work with celerybeat?

settings.py

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
   'login_mb': {
        'task': 'backend.tasks.login_mb',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=30),
    } ,
```

tasks.py

```
from matchbook.apiclient import APIClient
import logging
from celery import task

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@shared_task(bind=True)
def login_mb():
    mb = APIClient('abc', '123')
    mb.login()
    mb.keep_alive()
```

apiclient.py (wrapper library)

```
from matchbook.baseclient import BaseClient
from matchbook import endpoints


class APIClient(BaseClient):

    def __init__(self, username, password=None):
        super(APIClient, self).__init__(username, password)

        self.login = endpoints.Login(self)
        self.keep_alive = endpoints.KeepAlive(self)
        self.logout = endpoints.Logout(self)
        self.betting = endpoints.Betting(self)
        self.account = endpoints.Account(self)
        self.market_data = endpoints.MarketData(self)
        self.reference_data = endpoints.ReferenceData(self)
        self.reporting = endpoints.Reporting(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<APIClient [%s]>' % self.username

    def __str__(self):
        return 'APIClient'
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is not related to your wrapper library, there seems to be nothing wrong with your task.

The problem arises because you've defined your task with **bind=True** When done so, celery automatillca injects a parameter to the method containing information about the current task. So you can either remove **bind=True**, or add a parameter to your task method like so:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def login_mb(self):
    mb = APIClient('abc', '123')
    mb.login()
    mb.keep_alive()
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help. I wasn't sure what bind=True did. Thanks for your explanation